# Can a user get permission to send a mailing to contacts they can't access?

Tags: civimail, permissions

An organization would like to give permission to a volunteer to create and send a newsletter, but don't want to give the volunteer access to view the contacts they send to.  Is this possible?  I see the undocumented "CiviMail approval workflow" feature; could this be used somehow?